# Change divider color doesn't work with min. SDK 21

Tags: android

I have an android app, where I would like to change the divider color of my date picker.

This works fine until SDK 20.

SDK 21 => shows the default blue divider
SDK 23 => shows grey divider

SDK 15 - 20 => shows my green divider (Correct)

This is my code:

```
// DatePicker Set Divider Color
private void preparePicker() {
    try {
        Field datePickerFields[] = DP.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : datePickerFields) {
            if ("mSpinners".equals(field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object spinnersObj = field.get(DP);
                LinearLayout mSpinners = (LinearLayout) spinnersObj;
                NumberPicker monthPicker = (NumberPicker) mSpinners.getChildAt(0);
                NumberPicker dayPicker = (NumberPicker) mSpinners.getChildAt(1);
                NumberPicker yearPicker = (NumberPicker) mSpinners.getChildAt(2);
                setDividerColor(monthPicker);
                setDividerColor(dayPicker);
                setDividerColor(yearPicker);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("-->", "Unable to change date dialog");
    }
}

private void setDividerColor(NumberPicker picker) {
    Field[] numberPickerFields = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : numberPickerFields) {
        if (field.getName().equals("mSelectionDivider")) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                field.set(picker, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.picker_divider));
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Log.e("-->", "Illegal Argument Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                Log.e("-->", "Resources NotFound");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                Log.e("-->", "Illegal Access Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: you are using reflections, the field name might have been changed to something else, check the printstack of all Catch block

Comment: i updated my code with log.e - but i get no log messages

Comment: okay, after e restart of my android studio, i get this log:
"Unable to change date dialog" - and i have to change this line if ("mSpinners".equals(field.getName())) to if ("MODE_SPINNER".equals(field.getName()))

but same result

Comment: please also include ex.printStackTrace() to get exact message in catch of preparePicker(), also you can try to make Custom NumberPicker in order to avoid this hack

Comment: a custom numberPicker? what does this mean?